# Route53 Domain Transfer - Registry error - 2400 : Command failed (421 SESSION TIMEOUT)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am trying to transfer a domain using Route53 and after a few minutes I receive an email with the following error.

```
Registry error - 2400 : Command failed (421 SESSION TIMEOUT)
```

Anyone have any ideas what this means or how to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen your error. There is a document on transferring domains with error messages. The reason that I am responding is that I have seen domain transfers fail going to Route 53 without every learning why they failed. Maybe this will help you.

[NSI Registry Registrar Protocol (RRP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2832)

421 Command failed due to server error. Client should try again A
transient server error has caused RRP command failure. A subsequent
retry may produce successful results.